# Ubuntu gives "incorrect password" warning

Tags: password

Every since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, I keep getting an error message saying, "incorrect password".  I've never changed my password since starting to use Ubuntu.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you changed your keyboard layout recently?

Comment: you would not be the 1st to forget to turn on/ff capslock ;)

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

- You have your Caps Lock on.
- You changed your keyboard layout. Check the keyboard icon in the upper right.
- You are mistyping your password in some way.

Comment: if all things are fine and you still have the problem means , http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation with Kubuntu 14.04.1 I got "incorrect password" error on the X session, but when I switched to console it turned out that my password is expired so I have to set a new one. I have no clue why I wasn't allowed to log in and offered to change the password on GUI, Or at least warned about it.